# create a computed SQL column that maintains the running total orders each customer has

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I thought about using a trigger or function to solve the problem but I don't really know how to go about coding it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A running total is very easy in SQL Server 2012 using a window function.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to create view? view update every time a new row added or updated.
Views serve as query and look like a table.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should not persist the running totals, the possibility of the value becoming *stale* is high, instead you should go the route of View as suggested by @m-farhan. Still if you would want to persist the running total, then Trigger would be the safest bet. The Trigger ideally should fire a SQL query to accumulate the Customer's total and update the Total's column.